# let $a,b$, and $c$ be integers with $b \ne 0$, and $b|c$. Prove that $\gcd(a,b) =\gcd(a+c, b)$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

since $( b|c)$, $c = xb$
So, $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + xb, b)$
Euclidean algorithm shows shows that for $a=bq + r$, $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,r)$
This is where im stuck, I've approached this quesiton so many ways but can't figure out how to apply the algorithm for the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\gcd\;(a,b)=k$, then, $k|a$ and $k|b$. Clearly, $k|c$ as $b|c$. Now, this implies $k|(a+c)$ and $k|b$.

Now, we want to show if there exists an $m$ such that  $m|(a+c)$ and $m|b$, then $m|k$, as $k$ is the $\gcd(a+c,b)$.

Now, $m|(a+c) \implies m|a$ and $m|b$, from this it shows that $m|\gcd(a,b)$. Hence $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a+c,b)$

Comment: Im a bit confused with what u meant by 'm s.t' ?

Comment: I have improved it. It means there are more divisors, not necessarily only $k$. If there exists such an $m$, then we show $k$ is the largest divisor and hence it is the g.c.d @Draken147

Comment: On the middle part of the proof, u said that 'm|k as k is the gcd of (a+c,b). Do u mean k is the gcd of a,b because we havent proved the that yet? it was only proved that k is a divisor of (a+c) and b

Comment: $k$ is the greatest we have shown this. By showing that any divisor $m$ of $a+c,b$, will have to divide $k$.

Comment: oh ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since $b \mid c$, $\exists k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $c=bk$.
Now by Euclidean Algorithm, one always has $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a+bt,b)$ for any integer $t$. Now choose $k=t$.